# Select & replace unique identifier in selected rows in R

Tags: r, replace

I have a dataframe; please click on link to see the screenshot of the dataframe
[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ad1wO.png)

As you can see, in classes column, we have "negative.|uniqueidentifier" and few other factors like hyperthyroid. My primary concern is to select and replace all rows with "negative.|uniqueidentifier". I want to use only "Negative".

Also, for other columns where hyperthyroid is appearing with unique identifiers. I want to do same with them also.

Please help.

Comment: Images are not the right way to post data (or code). Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of your dataset.) Also, there are several rows with `negative.|uniqueid`. What makes that one special?

Comment: R is a free, open-source programming language and software environment for statistical computing, bioinformatics, visualization and general computing. **Provide minimal, reproducible, representative example(s) along with the desired end result. Use dput() for data and specify all non-base packages with library calls. Do not embed pictures for data or code, use indented code blocks.** For statistics questions, use http://stats.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `tidyr` package and the `separate` function.  Here's an example similar to your dataframe:

```
classes <- c(rep("negative.|185",5),rep("hyperthyroid.|3445"))
library(tidyr)
separate(as.data.frame(classes), col = classes , into = c("classes","classes_ID"), sep = ".\\|")
#       classes classes_ID
#1     negative        185
#2     negative        185
#3     negative        185
#4     negative        185
#5     negative        185
#6 hyperthyroid       3445
```